# Wordpress get single post without shortcodes

Tags: php, wordpress

I am retrieving the single post of wordpress like this.

```
function getPost($data){
    $post = get_post($data['id']);
    return $post;
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function ( $server ) {
    $server->register_route( 'get-post', '/get-post/(?P<id>[\d]+)', array(
        'methods'  => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'getPost',
    ));
});
```

How can I remove the shortcodes from the post content.

I tried this but not working.

```
$post = get_post($data['id']);
$post->post_content = strip_shortcodes($post->post_content);
return $post;
```

Answer (score 0):

if `strip_shortcodes()` function not works then  may be it will help you.

```
$content = preg_replace('#\[[^\]]+\]#', '',$post->content);
```

Comment: I tried this also, but this removes some other contents also from the post (Some of the post).